# android - How to display the symbol

Tags: android, symbols

I try to display the symbol of sections("**§**") then it will display unknown symbol.I tried alot but i am not getting. please can anybody help me.

```
Code
```

builder.setMessage(readEula(activity));

private static CharSequence readEula(Activity activity) 
    {

```
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try 
    {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getAssets().open(ASSET_EULA)));
        String line;
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) buffer.append(line).append('\n');
        return buffer;
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return "";
    } 
    finally
    {
        closeStream(in);
    }
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Displaying into where? `WebView` or `TextView` or `EditText` or somewhat?

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code and any logcat errors? It's hard to help without more information.

Comment: I want to use it in the alertdialog message.

Comment: Then, use user:appserv's answer. He's right.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
   yourTextView.setText("\u00a7");
```

or

```
   yourDilogBuilder.setMessage("\u00a7 bla-bla-bla....");
```

Comment: ya it's working but i want to use the text file from the assest instead of the direct text in that case it is not working please refer the code.